# Messaging Sessions chats being ended by agent suddenly in salesforce, but the agent is doing nothing. What it can be?

Tags: omnichannel, chat, messagingsession, bot, messaging

In my org, the einstein bot transfer the customer to an agent, and then they talk, so the specialist can solve the customer issues. But, sometimes, the chat is being ended suddenly, and, the messaging session says that "the session was ended by the agent". It has anything to do with some omnichannel setting? Also, anyone is using some key word to end the chat, I already verified it. What can it be?